# Extract dates from a specific json format with sed

Tags: json, bash, date, sed, grep

I have a json file including the sample lines of code below:

[{"tarih":"20130824","tarihView":"24-08-2013"},{"tarih":"20130817","tarihView":"17-08-2013"},{"tarih":"20130810","tarihView":"10-08-2013"},{"tarih":"20130803","tarihView":"03-08-2013"},{"tarih":"20130727","tarihView":"27-07-2013"},{"tarih":"20130720","tarihView":"20-07-2013"},{"tarih":"20130713","tarihView":"13-07-2013"},{"tarih":"20130706","tarihView":"06-07-2013"}]

I need to extract all the dates in the yy/mm/dd format into a text format with proper line endings:

`20130824`
`20130817`
`20130810`
`20130803`
...
`20130706`

How can I do this by using sed or similar console utility?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this line works for your example:

```
grep -Po '\d{8}' file
```

or with BRE:

```
grep -o '[0-9]\{8\}' file
```

it outputs:

```
20130824
20130817
20130810
20130803
20130727
20130720
20130713
20130706
```

if you want to extract the string after `"tarih":"`, you could :

```
grep -Po '"tarih":"\K\d{8}' file
```

it gives same output.

Note that regex won't do date string validation.

Comment: Also note that this method is going to fail if the structure changes. For example it is going to output 01234567 for that part: ``{"tarih":"20130824","tarihView":"24-08-2013","test":"0123456789"}`` Second solution will fail with this input ``{"tarih" : "20130824","tarihView":"24-08-2013"}`` without even outputting anything. So, it is a great solution if you're not planning to change the input file structure, but otherwise do not use this.

Comment: Could you please help me on this, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18428246/extract-some-particular-fields-from-a-specific-json-file

Answer (score 0):

This is VERY easy in python:

```
#!/bin/bash
python -c "vals=$(cat jsonfile)
for curVal in vals: print curVal['tarih']"
```

If I paste your example to `jsonfile` I get this output

```
20130824
20130817
20130810
20130803
20130727
20130720
20130713
20130706
```

Which is exactly what you need, right?

This works because in python [] is a [list](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) and {} is a [dictionary](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), so it is very easy to get any data from that structure. This method is **very safe** as well, because it wont fail if some field in your data contains `{` `,` `"` or any other character that sed will probably look for. Also it does not depend on the field position or the number of fields.